# Rotation and translation in 3D reconstruction using 2D images

Tags: image, matlab, 3d, modeling

I am trying to do 3D model reconstruction using 2D images from different views. I am following this example code from Matlab to get the desired results:
[Structure From Motion From Two Views](http://www.mathworks.com/help/vision/examples/structure-from-motion-from-two-views.html).

Following are the test images taken from the camera:

Manually taken images of 1st and 2nd image with translation of 1cm:
[image: manually taken images of 1st and 2nd image with translation of 1cm]

Overlay with matched features of first and second image:
[image: overlay with matched features of first and second image]

Manually taken images of 1st and 2nd image with translation of 2cm:
[image: manually taken images of 1st and 2nd image with translation of 2cm]

Overlay with matched features of first and second image:
[image: overlay with matched features of first and second image]

These are the translation vectors and rotation matrices I get for each case:

1cm translation:
translation vector:`[0.0245537412606279 -0.855696925927505  -0.516894461905255]`
rotation matrix:

```
[0.999958322438693  0.00879926762261436 0.00243439415451741;
-0.00887800587357739    0.999365801035702   0.0344844418829408;
-0.00212941243132160    -0.0345046172211024 0.999402269855899]
```

2cm translation:
translation vector:`[-0.215835469166982 -0.228607603749042  -0.949291111175908]`
rotation matrix:

```
[0.999989695803078  -0.00104036790630347    -0.00441881457943975;
0.00149220346018613 0.994626852476622   0.103514238930121;
0.00428737874479779 -0.103519766069424  0.994618156086259]
```

In documentation, it says it is relative rotation and translation between the 2 images.

But I am unable to understand what these numbers mean and what is the unit of the above values.

Can anyone at least let me know in what units are we getting the translation and rotation or how to extract the rotation and translation which is in any way comparable to the real world values like cm/mm and radians/degrees respectively?

Answer (score 1):

You can translate the rotation matrix into a [axis-angle-representation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axis%E2%80%93angle_representation) where you get the angles in radians. This can be done using the [vrrotmat2vec](http://se.mathworks.com/help/sl3d/vrrotmat2vec.html) function or by implementing a translater yourself by following [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix#Conversion_from_and_to_axis-angle) if you don't have access to the package. The angle will then be in radians.

When it comes to translation however you wont get it in a unit that makes sense in the real world, since you don't know the scale. This is unfortunately a problem with structure from motion in general. It is impossible to know if you take a image close to something small or far away from something large.

When using structure from motion to construct a 3D model this is fortunately not a problem since you still get relative distances correctly. Therefore you will be able to capture the scene (by following the rest of the tutorial) but you wont be able to say if something is 2cm or 2km tall, unless you have something in the image that you know the real life size of.

Hope it helps :)

Comment: In fact the last step of the tutorial explains how to measure things in the scene in metric distances if you know the size of a object

Comment: actually i have ground truth data which tells me the translation in x,y,z axis(that is been calculated by using the movement of camera) in millimeters. Is there is any way i could compare my translation with the ground truth values that are in millimeters? because i wanted to find the accuracy of the extracted values.